# IBM Watson Studio Desktop Download connection error

Tags: ibm-watson

When installing IBM Watson Studio Desktop version the download gets to around 66% then starts throwing errors such as:

The 'connections' download was interrupted. Check your network connection and restart IBM Watson Studio.

The 'shaper' download was interrupted. Check your network connection and restart IBM Watson Studio.

The 'node' download was interrupted. Check your network connection and restart IBM Watson Studio.

Despite my internet connection being constant the entire time. I am running the installer with admin perms and have restarted it many times.

Answer (score 1):

There is some download problems with the app, but if you close the installer and launch again, the installation is resumed.
Today I installed the WSD but I closed and restarted the install 4 or 5 times.